# Recyclerview onscrolllistener not working when RecyclerView inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I want to have a pagination for the recyclerview but , In my case , the recyclerView is inside a ScrollView. So the onscrollListener not working as expected. So I am planning to find the scroll end for the ScrollView and will fire the next page request.

Is this a good solution or Do somebody have a better idea?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fillViewport="false">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:orientation="vertical"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/headerContainer"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's not a good way to put RecyclerView inside  scrollView.Why you want scrollView?

Comment: Its always bad idea to have 2 scrollingviews. Why  do you need the ScrollView?

Comment: Actually I need a scrollview , since the whole content should scroll. And the content include a Header area , and below that a ViewPage with tabs .

Comment: Can you post your layout.

Comment: @X3Btel code posted

Comment: From what you posted you simply just dont need the ScrollView at all. You can attatch ScrollListener to the RecyclerView

Comment: @X3Btel Sorry this is the original code that have mentioned. Inside the viewpager i have a fragment that contain RecyclerView.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code for intercepting the RecyclerView scrolls and can fine tune your scroll events on basis of that, I hope it help

```
mList.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
            float rawX;
            int mSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(getActivity()).getScaledTouchSlop();

            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        rawX = event.getRawX();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                        rawX = 0f;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (Math.abs(rawX - event.getRawX()) > mSlop)
                            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Awesome! Calling lazyloading method inside ACTION_UP after these 2 lines helped me.
  v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                        rawX = 0f;
lazyloading(); //your method here